# A scene just disappeared and is nowhere to be found (not in trash or computer)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a project daily for a month now and when I closed the computer for about an hour and came back right now, my main game scene just disappeared from my project and is not in the project directory, computer or trash bin.

I don't know what to do, I found some similar posts with answers that this is normal and that projects or documents sometimes become corrupted and "disappear". It seems that Unity projects sometimes just miraculously disappear, does anyone know how this can be solved or what causes it?

Comment: Try to recover from a Time Machine backup.  (Then learn and start using Git for source code version control).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize this could be done. I also uploaded the remaining files on Git, when I figured one was missing.